# I cannot run Kafka through Idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-kafka, slf4j

I just downloaded the source code of Kafka from github. And I gradle it successfully.
But when I try to run it, it shows that " SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Process finished with exit code 1 "
I think I've already make the right property, and built the right directory tree.  And I guess the slf4j is just a warning which cannot prevent running this program.
And the property, directory trees and log showed like this.
It's very grateful to help me overcome it.
[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn2WE.png)

[my property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REKYB.png)

[the directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2yXt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slf4j, which ships with Kafka, is an abstraction layer over logging mechanisms.

Since it doesn't come with a default logging mechanism, it expects you to provide one.

If you add a logging library that supports slf4j (e.g. Logback, Log4j) to your classpath, the warning will disappear and you'll start seeing logs.

That said, I don't think that's what is keeping you from running Kafka. It will, however help you find the actual problem.

Comment: Thank you, I add a slf4j-nop to my classpath, but it's only shows that "Process finished with exit code 1" now. So is there any other helpful information for me ?

Comment: slf4j-nop is a "no operation" implementation, meaning it doesn't do anything. Replace it with Logback, and you'll see actual logs.

Comment: thank you, it works. But I used slf4j-simple stead of logback. And I see that what stop running is that the port and broker id are occupied. So I re-edit the server property. It works now